# How to install programmatically root CA silent without user interaction android

Tags: java, android, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I`m trying to install .crt file which looks something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

but i didn't find correct solution for my situation. Before asking this question i saw many questions, something like this solution  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657172/how-to-install-ca-certificate-programmatically-on-android-without-user-interacti)

Also tried this piece of code but i don't wan't user to be involved with certificate installation:

```
Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.root_sertificate);
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, cert.getEncoded());
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, "IAT Cert");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Third solution that i tried was that:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.root_sertificate);
// generate certificate from cert string
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(inputStream);
KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustStore.load(null);//Make an empty store
trustStore.setCertificateEntry("test_alias", cert);
```

but here i can't find anywhere this installed certificate. I will be glad if someone can direct me to some kind of solution if it possible of course.

Comment: This sounds like a proper security vulnerability if it's allowed without user input.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki i saw many answers for my second solution which i tried trustStore.setCertificateEntry("test_alias", cert); but when i tried to open web site which need to read my certificate its shows that there are no certificate found

Comment: Does the website have to read certificate (2 way SSL) or does the app needs to verify the website (1 way SSL)?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki the website have to read certificate for sure in my situation and because of that sys admin send me .crt file and told me that i need to import this certificate in to device because site work only with trusted devices

Comment: if this certificate is client certificate for 2-way TLS authentication, then the certificate is missing the private key. You may need to ask sysadmin for private key file (maybe in PKCS#12/PFX format) and install the certificate and private key in the store.